# Compose nested EventEmitters elegantly

Tags: javascript, inheritance, node.js, event-programming, composition

I am developing a server-side JavaScript tool, and trying to do so in a modular way.

I have a `Parser` class that is an `EventEmitter` - you call `parse` and it will eventually emit `data` and `end` events. It is generally invoked like so:

```
var parser = new Parser(options);

parser
  .on('data', handleData)
  .on('end', handleEnd)
  .parse();
```

Now I want to extend this Parser in a way that imposes some sort of state - rather than simply emitting `data` for every parse result, it tracks how the results change between parses. I have built another class called `Stateful` that accepts a `Parser` instance and is built around it (composition-style). It is an `EventEmitter` itself and emits `insert`, `update`, `delete`, and `end`. You use it like so:

```
var parser = new Stateful(new Parser(options));

parser
  .on(/* handle events */)
  .parse();
```

Now I want to extend this functionality further. In addition to tracking state, I want to track the order of these parse results according to some pre-defined sorting algorithm, as each parse result is emitted. This does have a performance hit over the `Stateful` parser, and there would be reason to use `Stateful` with tracking sort order, so I want to keep it separate. It will emit the same events as `Stateful`, but they will have some additional objects passed to their handlers.

**So what is the best way to do this?**

I could further nest composition, like so:

```
var parser = new Ordered(new Stateful(new Parser(options)));
```

But that seems smelly to me. `Ordered` relies upon being passed a `Stateful` and would break if it was just passed a `Parser`.

Alternatively, I could say that `Ordered` inherits from `Stateful`, but remember that `Stateful` communicates with events, which do not like to behave polymorphically. Take this example below. I used ES6 class pseudo-syntax for terseness, let me know if it is unclear at all. I am actually writing this in ES5.

```
class Stateful extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(parser) {
    this.parser = parser;

    parser
      .on('data', this.handleData.bind(this))
      .on('end', this.handleEnd.bind(this));
  }

  handleData(data) {
    if (isNew(data)) {
      this.emit('insert', data);
    } else {
      this.emit('update', data);
    }
  }

  handleEnd() {
    for (data in dataNotYetHandled()) {
      this.emit('delete', data);
    }
    this.emit('end');
  }
}

class Ordered extends Stateful {
  /* ??? */
}
```

The `handleData` and `handleEnd` methods emit events directly, so I cannot make use of them directly in the superclass implementation. I could separate the logic from the `emit` calls, but that would break encapsulation, requiring my subclass to make use of calls outside of its superclass's public interface.

What pattern would be best here? I am in control of all 3 classes and could make changes to the interfaces of any of them. Please let me know if I could provide any more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have decided to re-implement the solution using Node Streams, rather than simple events, allowing me to use `pipe()`.

Comment: Would love to see a example :) .. what about something like RXjs?